# What was the implant device Captain Marvel was using?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel-2019

In *Captain Marvel* we are shown that Vers/Carol has an implant that appears to help her control or regulate her powers, and lights up on occasion. What exactly is it, and what does it do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the film we learn it was implanted on her by the Supreme Intelligence when she was brought to the Kree. Carol/Vers is led to believe her powers were given by the Supreme Intelligence and can also be taken away via this implant.

Toward the end of the film Carol learns her true origin and is able to overpower the inhibitor implant because the Kree were never the source of her power.

Comment: This also reminds me of the device used on Quake/ Skye and the Inhumans in the later AOS season with the Kree.